# add a webform in a product checkout

Tags: forms, commerce, webforms

I would add a webform in the checkout step of a particular product. I need this feature because sometimes the products that i offer needs more information and sometimes the information that i need are different, so the webform that i should show could be change.

I would show the webform during the checkout, i don't want to have a webform that redirect to checkout (commerce webform module i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're needing product-related information, [Commerce Custom Product](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_custom_product) would be the way to go. If you're needing order level information, then you can create order-level fields and expose during checkout using [Commerce Fieldgroup Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes).

Finally, [this post on drupalcommerce.org](https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/7389/how-insert-werform-checkout-pane-or-page) seems to elude to getting a webform to work within a custom pane.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your question you should follow below steps:

1. Create a form using Webform and then in Webform >> Advance settings mark that webform as "Available as block".
2. Now you can see that webform as a block in Blocks page.
3. In block configuration you can set the option to display that block on specific page.

Let me know when you implement it.

Comment: you misunderstanding. I want a webform for just some type of product, i don't want alway the same webform for every checkout page